# Difference between real images and artifical images

Tags: image, opencv, difference

I'm trying to figure whether an image is *real* (fullframe), like:

[image]

or *artificial* (contains presentation information), like:

[image]

This is the context.

I got a video input file. This video contains frames with presentation and frames with an fullframe image.

I already wrote a code to find the vertical border of the presentation, but sometimes my code finds a border inside a fullframe image (e.g. windows,wooden panels in the back)

Now I want to decide before I search for the vertical border. I tried to determine a value for the structure in the images. Based on the idea that presentation got homogeneous areas and a fullframe image got more structure.

But this doesn't work pretty good.

Maybe you can give me some ideas to get this working.
I use OpenCV as image processing framework.

Comment: You should post the code you tried, and detail what _doesn't work pretty good_ means. Can you give some example? I think that a threshold on the amount of gradient with respect to the whole area is enough for this.

Comment: what about a photograph of a presentation? Is that "artificial" or "real"?